# what is the area of a symmetric lens with the circles having a radius of 35' being 60' apart

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I need this answer for work.  Ive tried for hours to figure this out. If anyone could help it would be much appreciated.   I need to find the area of a symmetrical lens of two circles who's radius is 35' and they are spaced 60' apart. Explaining the answer is not necessary but would be very useful to me in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Your lens is composed of two [circular segments](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_segment)  The dashed line in the Wikipedia figure bisects the segment between the centers.  You have $R=35$, and the bisector gives $d=30$, so $\theta=2\arccos \frac dR\approx 1.0822$  Then $A=2R^2(\theta- \sin \theta) \approx 488.058$ where the factor $2$, which is not in Wikipedia, accounts for the fact that you have two segments.